# Wrap column text according to the table width antd

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have used Antd Table to display some data. It has 2 columns and the second column can contain some long paragraphs. The issue is that Antd Table is not wrapping the text which is going outside the width of the table like in last row of the below image.

So can anyone help me in wrapping the text if it is greater than the table width.

[image]

Comment: A working example will be great.

Comment: Actually I'm using style={{ whiteSpace: 'pre'}} to give new lines in the data if it exists and because of this style, the text is not getting wrapped.